# SpringBoot 2.1.3 Security multiple available login page for first authentication

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, thymeleaf

I'm developing a `SpringBoot 2.1.3` + `Thymeleaf 3` + `Tomcat 8` WebApp. I have implemented `Spring Security` and all works well. Now I have a little problem because I want to realize two form login page, one for backoffice users and other one for all others users.

I don't wanna put both form in the same page, and  like to create a page with a simple form for backoffice users and a link that redirect to another page (with another form) for customer users.

I have read some and I have found just a way to Ordering the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` and creating multiple entry point but this way, I can log in with page with order 1 and then I can go the the other form page. It'isnt what I want to do.

Do you know if there is a way to do this??
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I found a way and it is pretty simple. I have configured the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` as follow:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/login-procout").permitAll() // login for furnishers
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin().loginPage("/login-officers") // default login page
            .permitAll()
            .successHandler(customAuthenticationSuccessHandler())
            .and()
        .logout()
            .permitAll();

    http.csrf().disable();
}
```

Then I create two `html` page `login-officers.html` and `login-procout.html` referred by `Controller` as follow:

```
@Controller
public class MyController {

   @GetMapping("/login-officers")
   public String loginOfficers() {
      return "login-officers";
   }

   @GetMapping("/login-procout")
   public String loginProcout() {
      return "login-procout";
   }

}
```

And in both page I have default `Spring Security Form`:

```
<form action="" th:action="@{/login}" method="post">
   <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Username"/>
   <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password"/>
   <input type="submit" id="login" value="Log In" />
</form>
```

I don't know if is the right way to do but it works.